# How to figure out what is blocking my connection on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, port

I have a program that uses a server's port 1099 but my computer cannot connect (times out). The PC having the trouble is running Windows 7. I have disabled Windows Firewall,  the antivirus, and the router has all ports open. Still I cannot connect to the server. I am using telnet  1099 but cannot connect.

Meanwhile, other PCs, on another network can connect with no problem.

Appreciate any tips for troubleshooting.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting on the PC?

Comment: connection is blocked, its timing out.

Answer (score 2):

By default a client should not have any problem connecting to a remote server, regardless of the port.  From the sound of things it seems more like a Router or Firewall on your network connection may either be blocking on restricting the connection.

I would check your router for any rules or restrictions in place.

Comment: thanks for the answer. as i said i disabled firewall in the router.

Comment: Like I said, most likely this sounds like an issue either with your network connection, internet connection or the server in which you are trying to connect.

Comment: No, its not an issue with firewall. I verified it:  with another PC the connection to that port is successful.

Comment: The issue is definitely with Windows, but it is very strange. I disabled all the firewalls and antiviruses, not helping.

Comment: Seems like the only solution is to reinstall windows.

Answer (score 1):

Could possibly be an application on your local PC already listening on port 1099, that could be causing the issue.

From a command line run: `netstat -a -n -b`

Look for a process using port 1099 and note down the PID ( process ID)

Then open Task Manager, click on `view - select columns` add `PID` ( this will add the PID information to every  process.

Kill the process and try again.

Comment: No, nothing is listening on that port. When I run telnet to 1099 it does not work, while to other ports it works. I verified its not firewall, because with another PC the connection to that port is successfull.

Comment: Hi X-man, what I meant was on your local PC. could be that something on the local PC is running on port 1099 or blocking port 1099. What would help is if you install wireshark on your PC and start logging all network data, then try to connect to the server on port 1099. Filter wireshark using server IP and port 1099 and paste the results here.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet would be to install a TCPdump tool on your PC and on the server and see if it's getting to the server. If it is then you know that the server for some reason is terminating your connection.

Comment: Its not getting to the server.

Answer (score 0):

First try a ping is the other side is visible, then a tracert to see at what network hub the communication stops...

Comment: This may be better as a comment on the question, asking if ping/traceroute show the network is okay.